# PHP and server, "Path Info"

Tags: php, url

In building a site in PHP, I have found that the URL is capable of having extra info that doesn't belong, i.e.

```
http://www.mydomain.com/index.php/extrainformation
```

I've read about it being apart of `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` but need to find a way to stop this information from being displayed as it is showing up in results of Google searches. Is this something I can prevent by adding a condition in my .htaccess file?

Any insight?

Comment: is it mandatory to use the url design, or are you able to change them and use the extra information through a querystring? e.g. http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?extrainformation .. I'm asking because query strings will be ignored mostly for indexing.

Comment: You can create a rewrite rule to redirect users to somewhere if index.php/<something> get called. You cannot "hide" the uri. If your application take that attributes to construct the page, removing it redirecting the user to somewhere may create a unuseful site.

Comment: @Daxcode, I'm not even sure how they're being generated. It seems to just be the links on the page. I don't know that they're application specific as they are only links and not items like "footer.php" or actual elements I'm purposefully including. I'm obviously quite new to the world of PHP and am feeling quite lost.

Comment: @user1161032 since path informations will be used to provide SEO friendly urls, I would recommend to change the url structure in using the query string. The value of this string is accessable through $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] then. Which application are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That information is technically a valid URL even if it is ignored by your web page. So if a search engine like Google finds a URL, probably through a link, that contains that extra information, and it pulls up a valid web page, they will display it in their results.

You can solve this a few ways:

1. Use [canonical URLs](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) to specify the proper URL without the extra information
2. Do a [301 redirect](https://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=301%20redirect) to the URL without the garbage information if it is appended to a URL
3. Return an error (HTTP 40x) that the URL is invalid

All three will prevent Google from indexing pages with those kind of URLs

Comment: in regards to the 301, would I need to do this for each instance of a url with extra info? The problem there would be finding them. I only noticed it because one link showed up in a google results page. I am wanting a more general solution that would prevent them from being found. If this is possible. Otherwise I will knock them out 1x1.

Comment: A well written mod_rewrite could handle multiple URLs so the 301 redirect wouldn't be tough to implement across your site. The canonical URL method is the easy to implement as you can easily add this programmatically to your content pages and it would handle every possible URL a page could have.

Comment: I went ahead and implemented canonical links on all the pages so I'll see if that clears it up in regards to Google. Theoretically it should so good call. Thanks for the brain kickstart.

Answer (score 0):

Those look like Apache's multiviews. Add this to your htaccess file:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Comment: Pretty sure it's not multiviews. Added that line to my htaccess file to verify and it had no affect.

Comment: I'm actually rather sure that those are MultiViews. Unless you've got some advanced mod_rewrite rule, of course.